# racket function, is it wrong or am i missing somethng

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, scheme, racket

Found this function in the book realm of racket:

```
(define (my-filter pred lst)
  (cond [(empty? lst) empty]
        [(pred (first lst))
         (cons (first lst) (my-filter (rest lst)))]
        [else (my-filter (rest lst))]))
```

Calling it with:

```
(my-filter (lambda (i) (> i 5)) `(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8))
```

gives:

```
my-filter: arity mismatch;
 the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
  expected: 2
  given: 1
  arguments...:
   '(2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
```

So i changed it to:

```
(define (my-filter pred lst)
  (cond [(empty? lst) empty]
        [(pred (first lst))
         (cons (first lst) (my-filter pred (rest lst)))]
        [else (my-filter pred (rest lst))]))
```

And now it works fine. So i was wandering if there's anything i missed there or if the book is wrong?

Comment: Looks like just a typo

Comment: @jozefg i edited the answer, i renamed it as my-filter2 in my rkt because  it clashes with the other one (they are in same file)

Comment: Not related to the question, but your use of the comma operator is quite confusing.

Comment: @sepp2k thank you for this, i am a beginner to racket. updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it turns out the book was wrong. found this in the realm of racket [home page](http://realmofracket.com/errata.html). I thought it could be something i didn't understand because it was my first day doing racket.

> page 114 The definition of the my-filter function takes in two
>   parameters, but only one is supplied when recurring. The definition
>   should read:

```
(define (my-filter pred lst)
  (cond [(empty? lst) empty]
        [(pred (first lst))
         (cons (first lst) (my-filter pred (rest lst)))]
        [else (my-filter pred (rest lst)))))
```

Comment: Thanks for linking to our errata page. Also, just FYI, our publisher is getting ready to perform a second printing. This updated copy will incorporate this fix and all of the other errata submissions we've received.